# How to multiply all columns in SAS by another column?

Tags: sql, sas

Suppose data set looks like:

```
A  B  C
1  2  0.2   
2  7  0.3
3  10 0.7
```

and I want to multiply columns A and B by C and update the values? What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what you want as output. This is a very basic question unless there's something missing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this is quite basic. Then again, basics are the most important bit.

```
data begin;
    input A  B  C;
    cards;
    1  2  0.2   
    2  7  0.3
    3  10 0.7
    ; 
run;

data wanted;
    set begin;
    AC=A*C;
    BC=B*C;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Here is an easy example.*/
/*Your first data set*/
data fisrt;
input A B C;
datalines;
1  2  0.2   
2  7  0.3
3  10 0.7
;
run;

/*The data you want to get*/

data product;
set first;
AC=A*C;
BC=B*C;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just looking to update the values of a and b try this:

```
data product;
set first;
A=A*C;
B=B*C;
run;
```

alternatively, you could try:

```
proc sql noprint;
     create table product as
     select a*c as a,b*c as b,c from first;quit;
```

and then compare run times to see which one runs faster